# Past exam question: Convergence of a series or not

Tags: convergence-divergence

1. Is the series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{k}}{k^2+1}$$ convergent?
   This behaves similar to $\frac{\sqrt{k}}{k^2} = \frac{1}{k^{3/2}}$ so do we use the comparison test???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for all $k\geq 1$,
$$
0\leq\frac{\sqrt{k}}{k^{2}+1}\leq\frac{\sqrt{k}}{k^{2}}=\frac{1}{k^{3/2}}.
$$
The series 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{3/2}}
$$
converges since $3/2>1$. Therefore, by the Basic Comparison test, your series also converges.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since $\frac{\sqrt{k}}{k^2+1} \le \frac{\sqrt{k}}{k^2}$, this is exactly the right approach. Then use the $p$-series test.